# Why is there an error like this when I install inoerp?

Tags: php, xampp

I am trying to install inoerp and am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function create_function() in C:\xampp\htdocs\inoerp\www\includes\engine\install\steps\complete_install.php:78
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\inoerp\www\includes\engine\install\steps\complete_install.php(20): getQueriesFromSQLFile('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\inoerp\www\includes\engine\install\steps\complete_install.php(115): importSQL('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', Object(dbc)) 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\inoerp\www\includes\engine\install\install_template.php(40): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') 
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\inoerp\www\install.php(44): include_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') 
#4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\inoerp\www\includes\engine\install\steps\complete_install.php on line 78
```

Comment: `create_function()` was deprecated as of PHP 7.2, and removed from PHP 8. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use the formatting options to format your code to be as readable as possible.